# Error google is not defined in Google Spreadsheet Sidebar - In Mozilla FF only

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm using a script in a Google Spreadsheet, when the user clicks a button in a sidebar, the following code is triggered:

```
google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close)
    .myFunction(form);
```

This is running perfectly in Google Chrome and Opera. The myFunction is executed in the server without any problems, but in Mozzila Firefox I get the error:

```
google is not defined
```

What do I have to do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with google.script.host.close(). If you remove it, it will work fine or if you put it in try and catch block, it will work in FF. I don't know why is it happening, but you can do in following manner,

```
<script>
function onSuccess() {
   try{
     google.script.host.close();
   }catch(error){
     console.log(error);
   }
}

google.script.run
    .withSuccessHandler(onSuccess)
    .myFunction(form);

</script>
```

Comment: Do you mean tha myFunction(form) is not executing with this code?